# xUnit won't run in 32-bit mode in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, x86, xunit

According to the documentation for xUnit, using the xunit.runner.visualstudio package and running a test from there is supposed to select the version of xunit with the proper bitness for the project's platform target.

In AnyCPU or X64 platform targets, xUnit runs (although the tests fail since one of the projects is supposed to interface with a DLL that doesn't support Any CPU).

My attempts to get xUnit to run in 32 bit mode all end with it picking the 64 bit version instead, and throwing a BadImageFormatException when it does. I also can't get the console runner to work no matter what I do. How do I get tests working on my 32-bit build of my project?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you get any update?

Comment: I don't think I ever got it working. I'm sure there is a way, however.